# Loading data mysql

Tags: mysql, file-io, load, load-data-infile

I'm trying to Load Data that look like:

```
2WIRE;3COM;3M;3WARE
```

And each of the companies I want to be in new row in table which contains columns: c_id (auto increment, not in file) and c_name <- I want to put these companies here.

I try do it this way:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path\routersmodels.txt' INTO TABLE routers.companies (c_name) LINES TERMINATED BY ';'
```

and I got error, any ideas how to do it correctly?

EDIT:

The error is:

> 14:58:34  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path\routersmodels.txt' INTO TABLE
>   routers.companies (c_name) LINES TERMINATED BY ';'    Error Code: 1064.
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'LINES TERMINATED BY ';'' at line 1  0.000 sec

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: 14:58:34 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path\routersmodels.txt' INTO TABLE routers.companies (c_name) LINES TERMINATED BY ';' Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LINES TERMINATED BY ';'' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: I moved the error into the question where it belongs.

Comment: thanks, any idea how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct it should 100% work without any error. Here in your case it seems that there is some permission issue with the file you are accessing.

Try giving the permission to file and re-check.

Comment: I'm on windows on admin acc and with all the privileges, Im using Workbench to execute sql command to load file from disk into database on wamp

Comment: My fault, you were right, moved file and it works. Thank you :)